# How can I add more options under advanced tab of a network adapter?

Tags: networking, network-adapter, adapter

I want to know how I can add more options on the "Advanced" tab of a network adapter.

[image]

Others can change the MAC address from here but I can't ...I have to use `Regedit` and do a lot of complicated things that's why I want to get more options.

Comment: *Others can change the MAC address from here* - They either have different 802.11 adapter then you or they have a different driver then you.  You should verify which is the case then either install the required device driver or replace the hardware itself with a 802.11 adapter with that feature.

Answer (score 2):

These are options provided by the driver. Usually a driver written for your specific hardware gives you more options than the generic one.

The driver may allow programs (and OS) to change more options than you can manually set in this window. But no driver will allow to successfully change an option that is not supported by your hardware.

To gain access to as many options as possible, you should seek the richest compatible driver first (but the driver richest with options doesn't have to be the best one; e.g. it may be buggy).